# automate the OAuth2 refresh_token process with SpringBoot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid

I have a `SpringBoot2` application, a MainApp as a `resource-server`, KeyCloak as `AuthorizationServer` and a maven module, which is related to the MainApp, as a `OAuth2LoginClient`.

In other words, in MavenModule I have the follow SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:idm.properties")
public class Auth0Provider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
            authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login().redirectionEndpoint().baseUri("/callback*");
    
    http.csrf().disable();
  }

  private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/idmauth/**")
  );
}
```

There is also a controller that intercepts the protected call:

```
@Value("${oauth.redirectURL}")
private String redirectURL;

@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/redirect")
public RedirectView redirectWithUsingRedirectView(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
            clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                    oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                    oauthToken.getName());

    String token = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    attributes.addAttribute("jwt", token);
    return new RedirectView(redirectURL);
}
```

This return the `AccessToken` to my frontend. Clearly in my `idm.properties` file I have the `spring.oauth2.client.provider` and `spring.oauth2.client.registration` info.

Now the MainApp is a `SpringBoot2` WebApp with this simple SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class Oauth2RestApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

And in it's `application.properties` just the line:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://<host>/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

All works fine but, when the token expire, the only way I have currently found to refresh my token
is to manually do this `HTTP-POST`:

```
POST /auth/realms/<audience>/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: <host>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 844
client_id=<my_client_id>
&client_secret=<my_client_secret>
&refresh_token=<refresh_token_previously_obtained>
&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe inside the SecurityConfig or with a specific path inside `spring.oauth2.x` properties?

Answer (score 1):

Note that [refreshing an access token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6) is done on the OAuth 2.0 client side.

This is done automatically by Spring Security if you have [configured a `WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet) to be used when requesting protected resources.

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
}
```

When you have done so, the expired `OAuth2AccessToken` will be refreshed (or renewed) if an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` is available to perform the authorization.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already read about the WebClient but the calls to my backend comes from angular with the accessToken inside Authorization Header. How can I use WebClient in a context like that?

Comment: In that case, it will be the responsibility of the Angular application to refresh the token, since it is the client in this scenario.

Comment: U mean spring boot, out of the box, willl not configure the backend to refresh the access token?  Note, assuming the UI is backend (e.g using thymleaf), not frontend app (e.g angular)